# Get maximum available register for Linux PCI device

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am currently debugging a Linux kernel driver.
I want to sweep a PCI device's mmio registers to scan for certain information.
This is the function I wrote so far.

```
void _sweep_registers(struct pci_dev *dev)
{
        int i;
        int activecontrolstatus;
        int activestatus;

        for (i = 0; i < AMD_P2C_MSG_INTSTS; i++) {
                activecontrolstatus = readl(privdata->mmio + i);
                activestatus = activecontrolstatus >> 4;
                dev_info(&dev->dev, "activecontrolstatus = %d / activestatus = %d",
                         activecontrolstatus, activestatus);
        }
}
```

Currently I am reading mmio until what's specified in `AMD_P2C_MSG_INTSTS` (which is `0x10694`).
But how far can I actually go?
I have zero knowledge of Linux kernel development and only rudimentary knowledge of C.

**Background**

My goal is to find information about which sensors of the [AMD Sensor Fusion Hub](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11407747/) are marked as active.
They *should* be under the register `0x1068C`, but are not on my system (it's `0x0`, but at least an accelerometer is available, so the bitmask should at least match `0x1`).
I want to see, whether they are stored somewhere else.

Comment: According to PCI specification the minimum alignment should be 4k. So, at least to 0x11000. But IIRC alignment usually goes based on upper bits, so, presumable to 0x1fffc (to 0x1ffff with byte accesses). To be sure, you need to look at the `dmesg` to  see this certain PCI device resources. `lspci -vv -nk ...` also might work. It will show you exact resource window reported by the device.

Comment: According to the background you gave, I think it might be that driver needs some quirks/update to support presumable newer version of hardware / firmware. How are you being sure you have active sensors?

Comment: zOMG, I looked at the driver, I doubt how they have tested it...

Comment: @0andriy Maybe not, but I have. With my latest patch of the patch, and `force_accel=1` set, I get a working accelerometer: https://gist.github.com/conqp/e8a0793406fbe7c9714f01f3078ea33a

Comment: So, it may be firmware bug or driver misconception, or... Best approach is to ask directly AMD developers in that thread.

Comment: I registered at patchwork.kernel.org but I do not seem to have the option to add comments to the respective patches. Maybe one needs to be a kind of administrator to do so.

Comment: Do you have a mail client? Save raw mbox and open it in your client. Reply as usual.